# Why does my app crash without any reason when I add an if condition?

Tags: xcode, conditional-statements, swiftui

I'm new to Swiftui , but my app crashes if I add a if condition , works fine other wise

My code is :

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var textfield_val = ""
    @State var viewIsBlur = true

    var body: some View {

            VStack {

                Rectangle()
                     .foregroundColor(.red)                                                                 
                      if self.viewIsBlur {
                    self.blur(radius: 100.0)
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each modifier results in the creation of a new `View` and the `if` statement doesn't make sense in that context. You can use the ternary operator instead:

```
.blur(radius: viewIsBlur ? 100.0 : 0.0)
```